# Make 100 PDFs with unique code

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I have a text document/csv with 100 unique codes that should be used for a gift card.

For the gift card, I need to provide 100 PDF's each with the unique code.

Is it possible to do this using Illustrator or InDesign? I'm thinking of making a textbox that can contain the code, but I don't know how to make 100 PDF's with the codes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used InDesign's "Data Merge" function. Works perfect from CSV!

Answer (score 2):

If you have uniqe code (and more variable data like QR-codes and so on):

Make textbox with code in your PDF, make it Variable and name Data Set, save Variable library. Edit XML file in your text/XML editor, copy and paste `<v:sampleDataSet  dataSetName="YourUniCode">`. Fill corresponding fields.

You may have to create first file with codes and then use Find & Replace in your editor to surround code with XML tags. Then copypaste results in XML file.

Load your XML file (Variable library) into Illustrator.

Use script to export each dataset in separate PDF.

I have [simple script on GitHub](https://github.com/amolok/ai.export/blob/master/export%20all%20datasets%20from%20current%20layer%20to%20PDF.jsx), you can adjust it to your specific needs.

---

If you have linear codes from `n` to `m` (1 to 100) you can import your PDF into template page to InDesign, make your text box with page number, make 100 pages and print it.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this myself but there are some excellent answers on this previous question:

[Insert a variable on many pages in Adobe InDesign to fill in when printing PDF](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6939/insert-a-variable-on-many-pages-in-adobe-indesign-to-fill-in-when-printing-pdf)